# Correctly shutting down a work stealing thread pool

Tags: c, multithreading, atomic

Given a work stealing thread pool system where each work item can generate new tasks in a threads local work queue - that can spill out to a global queue if full.

How would you safely and efficiently coordinate the shutdown of such a system?  Assuming you have basic atomic operations and critical section locks available only.

To clarify some more and simplify.  Say each thread grabs tasks from it's local work queue only (no stealing between other threads queues to simplify).  If it's local work queue is exhausted it will take a lock on the global work queue and steal work to add to its local work queue.  The local work queues require no locks as they are specific to each worker thread.

Using a simple flag or atomic count of 'active' worker threads won't work due to cases where other workers may spill new work onto the global queue where from another worker threads view it may have thought it was the only worker left with work.

All workers should exit only when there is no work left.

Comment: I voted to close the question because it's too broad. I believe you should focus your question and tell us what you tried so far. On a personal note, I would probably raise a "stop" flag and join all the threads. This doesn't promise shutdown, since existing tasks might run forever (they might call themselves)... so I would also make the flag public and check it within self-renewing tasks... I did something similar in a thread pool I wrote for a server.

Comment: Sorry I think it's quite specific.  Raising a stop flag doesn't work nor does a simple atomic count of currently active workers due to no guarantees of when visibility happens between threads.  Tasks causing infinite loops by submitting themselves would be an error in the design of the tasks not the pool itself.

Comment: Having a specific question doesn't mean it isn't too broad. The "too broad" refers to possible answers, side you are asking for "how to..." you might get a lot of opinions about what works. There isn;t a "correct" answer.

Comment: I've edited in some more clarifications and a simplification if that helps?

Comment: I read the update and a flag is still your best bet. Every thread should make sure all personal and global queues are empty before returning. If you're just decreasing a non-bool counter flag, then the higher value threads (the ones leaving the thread pool) don't need to check the global pool unless the flag is `0` (the thread pool being closed). I don't see why this wouldn't work.

Comment: You may want to try this question on [**Programmer's StackExchange**](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) which in general caters to broader opinion based code design questions.

Comment: @Myst It won't work like that because even though a worker may think there is no more work because its local and the global queue are empty, another worker may have generated new work that overspills its local work queue and needs to be added to the global work queue - in which case that first worker should stand a chance to be picking that new work up.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks I didn't realise there was a different site for that kind of thing but I am not sure where this question belongs in that regard or how to move it if so.

Comment: @iam , Yap, that's true. The threads will not shutdown together unless you sync their shutdown process (probably using an array of "waiting to finish" flags, which I don't recommend)... But I don't see the problem. All tasks will be handled. Any spill-overs made by the last thread will eventually get handled by the last thread.

Comment: @Myst If you think about the case of major work imbalance, where one of the workers generates a large amount of child tasks that should be ideally spread across all workers via the global work queue.  Then you really don't want any of the other workers to have prematurely exited.

Comment: @Myst I am not sure if there is maybe some heavyweight but reliable solution using an array of flags/data with a mutex/lock per flag that has to do with each worker being in some sort of stage of promising not to generate new work until a stage of communication between all of them have finished?

Comment: @iam - I'm not sure that's true. We are referring to the last stages of program exit. The difference in performance for the extra workload (multi-threaded vs. a worst case single threaded) probably won't justify having the other threads poll at a completion flag. But, again, if you want to use two flags instead of one, that's fine. As to existing solutions, I don't know of any, but a semaphore might work to count promises (when promises == number of threads, we're done)...

Comment: @Myst Well it's possible that due to work inbalance a work item may well spawn more work then any that preceded it across all the works previously - so in which case the assumption that things are exiting isn't really true.  I'm trying to decipher one of the original papers on work stealing queues but it's hard going unfortunately for me.  Also implementations I have actually found online all have bugs to do with this.

Comment: @iam , Good luck! I still found that this isn't worth the extra effort (single threaded execution vs. multi-threaded for the last task cycle), and if that's the only issue with my [thread pool](https://github.com/boazsegev/c-server-tools/blob/master/src/libasync.c), I'm probably lucky ;-)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @myst doing 99% of the work single threaded under some circumstances doesn't seem like a "minor issue" - at least for production code to me.

Comment: @iam *If you think about the case of major work imbalance, where one of the workers generates a large amount of child tasks that should be ideally spread across all workers via the global work queue. Then you really don't want any of the other workers to have prematurely exited.*  Then **don't** have the workers exit - have them block on the global queue (assuming that each worker's local queue can only be populated by the owning worker).

Comment: @AndrewHenle Regards "have them block on the global queue" I am not sure how you intend that to work? Thanks.

Comment: @iam You haven't implemented your work queues such that a worker thread can block in a call to get a unit of work from the queue until there's actually work in the queue?  [Here's a Java example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)  Note that it's implemented in the very basic `java.util...` class - it's a fundamental part of the Java specification.

Comment: @Voo , we are talking only about the last cycle of work. If 99% of the work is performed in the last cycle, there's a whole different issue at stake.

Comment: @Myst Not really. It can happen that all but one thread are finished with all their work while one thread is still working. If you don't take care all threads finish and only *then* the last thread generates lots of new data. The whole idea of work stealing is to handle unbalanced workloads, so there's a reasonable assumption that this case is reasonably handled - at least I would have it. Cilk also doesn't have this problem, so I'd check out Leiserson's cilk-5 paper for inspiration (I can look for the paper at home later if need be).

Comment: @Voo Finally someone who understands the issue more :-)  I didn't know about clik - I shall have a read thank you.

Comment: @Voo , I understand the possibility but not the context. All threads wait for tasks before the "stop" flag is set. All normal tasks are scheduled before the "stop" flag is set. Before setting the "stop" flag, all high cost schedulers are notified (i.e., incoming IO channels are closed) and clean up tasks are scheduled. Now the "stop" flag is set and we have the tail of the workload and cleanup to contend with. If there are heavy task schedulers still active, it's a design flaw in the signaling stage. If 99% of the work is now starting it's a design flaw. Flags are still the answer.

Comment: @gnat - my bad, I should have mentioned a request for migration, etc.. Will do next time.

Comment: @myst I'm talking about a standard work stealing implementation, so you don't have anything explicit as " high cost schedulers". You have tasks that execute, add new work to queues and ask for more work when they finished their current work. I don't want to know how they're producing more work. The problem is easy with heavy handed locking but it's interesting on how to do it efficiently.

Answer (score -1):

The biggest requirement would be to have some way of saving the definition of each task so the state of pending tasks can be saved to persistent storage. Then implement a "stop" flag (with a mutex on it). The method to get a task from the pool for execution checks that flag and, if it's set, returns a "terminate work thread" indication (distinct from a "no tasks available" result that makes the thread wait and try again). Threads terminate when they get that indication, and the overall pool management thread waits until all work threads have terminated and then terminates the pool. The main program has to wait until the pool is terminated and the pool management thread exits, once that happens it's safe to terminate the program. If the program needs to continue to run and restart the pool later, that's also the condition that must be met before it can do anything that would affect the pool configuration or restart the pool.

Comment: I'm not sure why saving the state of pending tasks are an issue - they are either in global or local work queues or in registers in flight within the worker threads.  There is no overall pool management thread either right now - just a pool of identical worker threads.  The trouble is the fact workers can generate new tasks from the tasks they are running, that can spill out to the global queue, which causes problematic edge cases where workers think other ones may have finished using simple flags or a counter but in fact there is still work left.

Comment: @iam There's either work in the queue(s), or there isn't.  Why should workers care about what other workers are doing?  It seems like you have a way too-complex system that's out of control.

Comment: @iam Exactly. Persistent storage is needed because either you stop threads from generating work (which means they may need to stop mid-task) or you stop them from getting new work (which means unstarted tasks in the queue). You need a management thread because something needs to wait for work threads to stop, restart them if they end early and keep track of whether they've all shut down correctly and when the pool is safely and completely shut down.